# There is a bridge eror

Tags: tails, bridge, censorship

I am from Turkey where the Tor network is censored. I am using Tails 2.10 so I needed to use bridges which I took from https://bridges.torproject.org/. They were obfs4 bridges. I did tried it multiple times, but doesnt work. I use a sandisk usb as a live stick.

Here is the log could you please help me solve this issue.

```
04/02/2017 17:57:09.800 [NOTICE] New control connection opened from 127.0.0.1.
04/02/2017 18:01:36.400 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or 
accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.
04/02/2017 18:01:36.400 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
04/02/2017 18:01:36.400 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9061
04/02/2017 18:01:36.400 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9062
04/02/2017 18:01:36.400 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
04/02/2017 18:01:36.400 [NOTICE] Opening DNS listener on 127.0.0.1:5353
04/02/2017 18:01:36.400 [NOTICE] Opening Transparent pf/netfilter listener on 
127.0.0.1:9040
04/02/2017 18:01:36.400 [NOTICE] Renaming old configuration file to "/etc/tor/torrc.orig.1"
04/02/2017 18:01:36.800 [NOTICE] New control connection opened from 127.0.0.1.
04/02/2017 18:01:37.200 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server
04/02/2017 18:01:37.400 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server
04/02/2017 18:03:48.000 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory
server. (Connection timed out; TIMEOUT; count 3; recommendation warn; host 9D1295EE7E6112A328545327AF88EF00CD2668FE at 42.112.22.30:443)
04/02/2017 18:03:48.000 [WARN] 2 connections have failed:
04/02/2017 18:03:48.000 [WARN] 1 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object)
04/02/2017 18:03:48.000 [WARN] 1 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE
04/02/2017 18:07:39.600 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Transparent pf/netfilter listener on 127.0.0.1:9040
04/02/2017 18:07:39.600 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured DNS listener on 127.0.0.1:5353
04/02/2017 18:07:39.600 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
04/02/2017 18:07:39.600 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9061
04/02/2017 18:07:39.600 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9062
04/02/2017 18:07:39.600 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
04/02/2017 18:07:39.600 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.
04/02/2017 18:07:39.600 [NOTICE] Closing old Transparent pf/netfilter listener on 127.0.0.1:9040
04/02/2017 18:07:39.600 [NOTICE] Closing old DNS listener on 127.0.0.1:5353
04/02/2017 18:07:39.600 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
04/02/2017 18:07:39.600 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9061
04/02/2017 18:07:39.600 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9062
04/02/2017 18:07:39.600 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
```

Comment: That bridge appears to be down, so I would expect to see it time out. I'd recommend you try using a pluggable transport, like `obfs4` or `meek-amazon` or `meek-azure`.